# How to configure Apache to work with current version of PHP?

Tags: php, apache-2.4

The problem can be simply shown. My goal is to overcome this error message:

http://jfknumbers-forum.org/phpBB3/

[Error Message from phpBB application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFD8p.jpg)

I made a HUGE mistake attempting to build Apache from source. I said: "How hard can it be? ./configure, make, make install".

Famous last words: long story short, the VPS had to be re-OSd. It seems that I managed to kill systemctl.

Now I need to put together:

(a) Apache 2.4.6 from yum

(b) PHP 7.0.27 from CentOS SCL

Here's the deal: when you install Apache via yum, it looks for the **official** PHP.

I found a possible solution here:

[PHP 7 - Apache Configuration](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_apache_configuration.htm)

This is what I have:

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

This is what I need:

```
LoadModule php7_module modules/mod_php.so
```

I seems that my problem is that Apache installed via Yum was not built with the option to generate the module mod_php.so (aka libphp5.so)

Is there any way to locate that magic file?

So I am back to square one: Will I have to build Apache from source and specify that I need to include support for PHP 7??

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use PHP as a module? It's more efficient and secure to use it via PHP [FastCGI Process Manager (FPM)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php).

Comment: Installing `rh-php70-php` also installs `httpd24-httpd` instead of `httpd`. If you're doing SCL, why don't you use that? `rh-php70-php` also installs required library `librh-php70-php7.so` which is SCL's version of `mod_php`.

Comment: Thank you so much to Esa and M. Forsetti! I will try/compare both solutions.

Comment: Also, your error message says you need at least PHP **7.1**.

Comment: Stop what you're doing and reinstall with CentOS 8. Then you avoid this problem entirely.